# Having a web application listen for data without a server

Tags: javascript, web-applications, proxy, serial-port

For my job, I am researching a new means of accessing data from a web application created in either HTML or Javascript.  The situation is that we have a proxy that takes data from a computer's serial port and broadcasts it as regular TCP data on the Local Host.  We have web application that runs on the local system and we want it receive that data that is being broadcasted, however we want to implement this without creating a server to acquire said data.

So far I have been researching and googling for a solution but my search hasn't been fruitful.  If there exists a means for a web application to acquire data being broadcasted from a proxy, I would like to know.  Also we are running the web application locally from file:\ in IE11.

This stack overflow question is somewhat similar to our situation, however we cannot use Flash or Adobe Air: [AS3 socket class connection with serproxy and sending data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7932551/as3-socket-class-connection-with-serproxy-and-sending-data)

Comment: Wouldn't the proxy be the server?

Comment: the proxy is broadcasting regular TCP data on the local host and our web app runs on the local system (basically a console app with web based code)